# BLDC Regenrative ESC and LiPo

Tags: remote-control, lipo, motor-controller, brushless-dc-motor

I am currently working on a project where I want to implement a Brushless dc motor (like the [Turnigy C2226 - 1800kv](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbycity/store/uh_viewItem.asp?idProduct=5384)) to run in-hub of an RC car. I need this entire project to be as lightweight as possible. Also Torque is way more important than speed.

I have the following questions:

1. Do you get any commercial BLDC Regenerative ESC for this class of motor? If not, I'll have to build one from scratch based on [dlginstructables article](http://www.instructables.com/id/BLDC-Motor-Control-with-Arduino-salvaged-HD-motor/?ALLSTEPS).
2. Is this the best motor to do this with or can anyone suggest something better or different? As I mentioned, I'd like to use a motor that can fit into the hub of an RC car wheel. (Not decided on the size yet though, so still flexible.
3. Can you charge a 3S LiPo directly using this configuration or would I have to implement a Balancing circuit as well (any suggestions for a small, simple and lightweight version of this would also be cool - if required)?

Any help, suggestions and or comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: I highly doubt you'll find anything "commercial" that will work on that small of a motor.  Why won't an ESC from the same manufacturer work?  http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbycity/store/__2161__TURNIGY_Plush_12amp_2A_BEC_BESC.html  It's possible that 4 quadrant operation (regenerative braking) won't be as big of a gain as you think.  Can you share more details about the application?

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: Motor selection question is probably getting somewhat off-topic -- you may want to try http://robotics.stackexchange.com/ instead. Anyhow, do you plan to integrate a gear box as well? This motor is probably not suited for direct drive of RC car wheel.

Answer (score 0):

In response to part 3, by "using this configuration" I assume you are talking about the regenerative breaking part of the instructables article (which has no cell balancing)?

When charging more than one LiPo cell in series, it is recommended that you have a balancing circuit of some kind. Without it, after some time, the cells WILL have disproportionate amounts of charge and the batteries will die sooner than expected.

Comment: Wild guess here, but I'd assume regenerative breaking would not be the only way to charge the battery. It would rather serve to increase battery life between proper recharge. If a proper balancing charger is used regularly, then the cell imbalance due to non-balancing regenerative breaking would remain minor.